# Is there some kind of fully sandboxed "Chromium-based webview" which I can use to test my webpages with?

Tags: web-development, web-browser, chrome, web, chromium

My only installed browser is Pale Moon. It's an old fork of Firefox. I cannot install Chrome, Firefox, Chromium, Brave, Edge or anything like that on my computer for security/privacy reasons. But since 99% of all people sadly use Chrome or a "Chrome skin", I'm simply forced to support that "platform".

I know about BrowserShots. It will allow me to get an idea of what my pages look like, but only once it's already "live". Also, it doesn't let me actually test anything such as scrolling or interacting with the site. Forms and menus could be messed up in ways that don't show up on the still picture I'll get from BrowserShots.

I'm aware of the other, payware service which actually gives me such a "live view", but I can't pay money and can't trust a third party either way.

I've previously tried out Chromium many times. Touted as a "Chrome minus the Google spying", it's actually nothing like that. It's full of Google stuff, not to mention hosted/built by them.

What I'm looking for is some kind of project specifically made to fully encapsulate the "Chrome engine" ("Chromium" if you will) in a minimal GUI window which does not in any way communicate with the outside world. That is, not one network package must leave my machine. All my in-development pages are hosted on `http://127.0.0.1/project/`.

Setting up a virtual machine would not solve this as "localhost" there is not "localhost" on the host machine. Not to mention the extreme hassle of dealing with the installation and maintenance of such a thing.

It actually surprises me if there is no such active open source project. I suspect that there is, but I've just been unable to find it myself.

I'm trying to interactively "test" localhost-hosted webpages on my Windows machine in the most used engine without using spyware.

Please don't link me to some dead project or something which you haven't tried yourself.

Comment: Since you're using Windows, you're already victim of lots of spyware (specially on Windows 10), tons of packages are already leaving your network. If you have such a need that nothing leaves the computer, use a firewall instead for the browser and a Chrome clone.